# Specifying titleWidth for ShinyDashboard Title not Working

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

Am trying to specify the width of my Shiny Dashboard title as is explained [here](http://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#sidebar-width). However I keep getting the error `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.`, but only when I add the extra line for specifying title width `titleWidth = 400`. Withouth the line, the app runs fine (there is no app just a skeleton page to reproduce the error).

Code is as below...Any help greatly appreciated.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Title Which is Kinda Long",
    titleWidth = 400
    ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using version 0.4, the new version which got updated on the 17th of June 2015 is the 0.5. So just update the library `shinydashboard`

Look here the updates in the bottom for your case http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/shinydashboard/NEWS